# Why isn't move_upload_file is always returning false in the given code?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload an image using php and mysql and below is the code used..

index.php

```
<form action="submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; font: 12px Tahoma;" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<input name="uploadedimage" type="file">
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input name="Upload Now" type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</td>
</tr>


</tbody></table>

</form>
```

submit.php

```
<?php

include("mysqlconnect.php");

function GetImageExtension($imagetype) {
    if (empty($imagetype))
        return false;
    switch ($imagetype) {
        case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
        case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
        case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
        case 'image/png': return '.png';
        default: return false;
    }
}

if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    $file_name = $_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name = $_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype = $_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext = GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename = date("d-m-Y") . "-" . time() . $ext;
    $target_path = "images/" . $imagename;



    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedimage']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        $detail = date("Y-m-d");
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `image_upload`(`id`, `image`, `detail`) VALUES (NULL,'$target_path','$detail')";
        if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
            echo $conn->error;
        } else {
            echo "Successfully inserted. ";
        }
    } else {

        exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
    }
}
?>
```

Table structure:

```
#   Name        Type    Collation     Attributes    Null Default  Extra
1   id(Primary) int(11)                              No   None    AUTO_INCREMENT
2   image       blob                                 Yes  NULL      
3   detail     varchar(500) utf8_general_ci          Yes  NULL
```

Every time I execute this it always shows me "Error While uploading image on the server" I don't understand why. Can someone let me know where am I going wrong and how can I improve my implementation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your directory exist or not and have write permission

Comment: permissions to the directory are given already still it doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

add this line before moving file.

```
if (!file_exists($target_path )) { mkdir($target_path , 0777, true); }
```

this will add the folder if not exist.. with all permissions.

Comment: I tried adding this but still it gives the same output

Comment: It does not give any error, it just goes to the else block of the move_uploaded_file code :
 else {

        exit("Error While uploading image on the server");
    }

Answer (score 0):

Alter your table structure for image as varchar(255) and check if that works